# Repmgr and PostgreSQL data_directory permission problem

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

I've followed the instructions to set up a replica server of PostgreSQL with `repmgr`, But I can't start the PostgreSQL service because of a permission problem.

On the stand by server, I have this on my `/etc/repmgr.conf` file:

```ini
node_id=2
node_name=aws-replica
conninfo='host=<REDACTED> user=repmgr dbname=repmgr port=5432'
data_directory='/mnt/data/postgres/data'
log_file='/var/log/repmgr.log'
```

As you can see, I've changed the location of the data directory to `/mnt/data/postgres/data` and also updated the `postgresql.conf` file with the same information.

When I try to start the PostgreSQL service, I get this error on `journalctl`:

```
FATAL:  data directory "/mnt/data/postgres/data" has wrong ownership
HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
```

The folder in question is owned by a normal user, the same one that runs `repmgr`. If I set the ownership of the folder to `postgres:postgres`, then `repmgr` can't perform any operations because it can't access the folder. I tried joining the `postgres` group, but the service won't start unless the folder has `700` permissions, so it's pointless to join the group.

So, I'm either not being able to start `postgresql` or `repmgr`. What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I created a postgres DB using `innitdb`, which wasn't necessary. I deleted the database and then ran `repmgr` as the `postgres` user, and it worked.